# Как отправить картинку в ресурсы навыка Яндекс Алисы на Python?

Tags: python, requests, яндекс-алиса

Всем привет!

Мне нужно отправить в навык несколько десятков сгенерированных картинок.

Следовал инструкции:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как бы ни старался, в ответ всегда получаю 400 BAD REQUEST. Ниже скрин участка кода из моего проекта. Код сгенерирован конвертером curl -> python requests, чтобы наверняка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у кого-то есть опыт работы с навыками, прошу у вас помощи! Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [инструкции](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/), у вас неправильный формат параметра с файлом. Попробуйте так:

```
...
files = {'file': open('src/temp/tempimage.png', 'rb')}
...
```